# How do I hide a tab in a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-widget, tabactivity

I have created three tabs in [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29).

How can I hide one tab at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the tab you must remove it from the TabWidget. Just setting INVISIBLE is not enough. So, to hide the tab:

```
tab = getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabPosition);
getTabHost().getTabWidget().removeViewAt(tabPosition);
```

And to show that tab again:

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().addView(tab, tabPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the tabWidget you can do so by setting the visibility to `GONE`/`INVISIBLE` like:

```
getTabWidget().setVisibility(TabWidget.GONE);
```

Comment: getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabPosition).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

For Removing the particular tab from tabwidget :

> tab = tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabPosition);
>   tabhost.getTabWidget().removeView(tab);

and for adding it back to tabwidget :

```
 tabhost.getTabWidget().addView(tab);
```

OR

```
 tabhost.getTabWidget().addView(tab,tabPosition);
```